# Grouping result by date in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

This SQL statement

```
SELECT `ip`, `when` FROM `metrics` WHERE `vidID` = '1' GROUP BY DATE('when')
```

returns one result, even though multiple are present in the table with different dates. I've tried using `DATE_FORMAT` as well. Am I doing something stupid?

`When` is a timestamp column with full timestamp, including hours, minutes and seconds. I'm trying to just group by results by day/month/year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're grouping by the constant string `'when'` instead of the field `when`.

Use this instead:

```
GROUP BY DATE(`when`)
```

Sounds like you want to count the IP addresses for a given date:

```
SELECT COUNT(`ip`) AddressCount, `when`
FROM `metrics` 
WHERE `vidID` = '1' 
GROUP BY DATE(`when`)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, Welbog... goes to a syntax error on that

Comment: you need to use the FROM_UNIXTIME() function on this field first, as you are saying it's in a timestamp.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1


... that's with the only when now being DATE(when)

Comment: @WiseDonkey: Put `when` in backticks. It's a reserved word. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, GROUP BY is used in conjunction with some aggregate function (like SUM, say) to compute the result set by one or more columns.  What are you trying to accomplish here?  Do you mean to sort, or just get a collapsed list of which IPs have records on which dates?

Comment: latter. I'm just trying to get number total number of records for a date for now, and then total number of unique ips in another query later.